# Auto Search Set categories to cannot be focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing an auto search project.
I add the categories but the categories can be focused.

For example: `Africa` is one of the categories and focused, how can I set it to cannot be focused?

Picture for example

[image]

Please also see my codes of renderMenu

```
function renderMenu(ul, items) {
    var that = this;
    currentCategory = "";
    $.each(items, function (index, item) {
        if (item.category != currentCategory) {
            ul.append("<li class='autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
            currentCategory = item.category;
        }
        var li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
    });
```

and my codes of autosearch

```
   $("#search")
        .myautocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            source: input_data // Eg. { label: "Angola", category: "Africa" }

        });
```

Comment: Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560207/jquery-autocomplete-canceling-focus-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this with each change in the search Query `document.activeElement.blur()` it'll do.